# Cell reference between two sheets (one with variable name)

Tags: excel, vba

I've created macro which on button click creates new sheet based on template, place it as last sheet, and names it with ActiveCell value in main sheet ("Lista") (company names). In the new sheet, in cells B2:B5 I want to copy values (company information) from main sheet: columns B to E, however row is dependent on the selected company. The code is below:

```
Sub HistoriaDostaw()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim activeWB As Workbook
Dim FilePath As String
Dim ShtName As String
Dim CopyInfo As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Set activeWB = Application.ActiveWorkbook
FilePath = "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Szablony\HistoriaDostaw1.xltm"

On Error Resume Next

ShtName = ActiveCell.Value2

If Not WorkSheetExists(ShtName) Then

Set wb = Application.Workbooks.Open(FilePath)
wb.Worksheets(1).Copy After:=activeWB.Sheets(activeWB.Sheets.Count)

activeWB.Activate

activeWB.Sheets(activeWB.Sheets.Count).Name = ShtName

wb.Close False

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End If
End Sub

Function WorkSheetExists(ByVal strName As String) As Boolean
   On Error Resume Next
   WorkSheetExists = Not ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(strName) Is Nothing
End Function
```

I have tried using copy/paste method (placed within sub section) starting with just single cell but doesn't work:

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Lista").ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets(activeWB.Sheets.Count).Range("B2").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
    False
```

Also this method:

```
activeWB.Sheets(activeWB.Sheets.Count).Range("B2").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Lista").ActiveCell.Range.Offset(0, 1).Value
```

Perhaps I incorrectly refere to the newly created sheet. Or place the code lines wrong. Can you please help me?

Comment: You should read about best practices. Don't use activecell, as it is volatile. Also don't make use of select and activate, rather reference the worksheets explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this.

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Lista").Select
activeWB.Sheets(ShtName).Range("B2").Value = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value
```

if this is not Working try

```
MsgBox activeWB.Sheets(ShtName).Range("B2").Value
```

and

```
MsgBox ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Lista").ActiveCell.Range.Offset(0, 1).Value
```

to find out where the Error happens